# “How to fix ‘sed + grep no return status when no match’ error in shell”

Tags: shell

When I run a shell script with "sed + grep", it can't continue when I run a "sed" command.

```
x=`eval sed -n -e '1,"$"p' test.txt | grep "googoo"`
```

which will chuck following command.

I do some testcases which is listed as below, 123 has been printed, and 4 can't be printed.

I have tried on csh and bash.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

echo "End Time 1: `date +%T` `date +%D`"
x=`ps -ef | grep "gogogo"`
echo "End Time 2: `date +%T` `date +%D`"
x=`eval sed -n -e '1,"$"p' test.txt`
echo "End Time 3: `date +%T` `date +%D`"
x=`eval sed -n -e '1,"$"p' test.txt | grep "googoo"`
echo "End Time 4: `date +%T` `date +%D`"
```

I got result as below:

```
End Time 1: 22:24:02 05/23/19
End Time 2: 22:24:02 05/23/19
End Time 3: 22:24:02 05/23/19
```

and

```
echo "End Time 4: `date +%T` `date +%D`"
```

can't run.

and the content of test.txt is:

```
testtest
testtest
```

which is something not match

Comment: It is not clear, please do add more information with sample of input and expected output in your post in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: The exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) are well worth reviewing when deciding whether using `-e` is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
```

This set's the `set -e` flag. From [posix shell set manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/set.html) emphasis mine:

> -e
>   When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or returns an exit
>   status value >0, and is not part of the compound list following a
>   while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR list,
>   and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word, then the **shell
>   shall immediately exit**.

From [man grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

```
Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines
       were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.
```

As the command `grep` in the pipeline inside a command substitution returns a non-zero status:

```
x=`
  eval sed -n -e '1,"$"p' test.txt  | # will not print any googoog
  grep "googoo" # thus this will return with 1
` # command substitution exit status is the exit status of the last command executed
# the last command executed is grep - so command's substitution exit status is 1
# the exit status of variable assignment is the exit status of the last command executed
# the last command executed is command substitution - it's exit status was 1
```

The command returns with nonzero status, which terminates your script.

Notes:

- Eval is evil, unneeded there, and using it is bad. Just `sed -n -e '1,'"$p" test.txt`...
- Using backticks is [deprecated](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Don't use backticks. Use `$( ... )`, which looks cleaner, more readable, allows for nesting.
- Remember about `-e` shell flag. Use it wise and learn to handle exit statuses from commands.